# How to turn this SQL query into a Entity Framework lambda expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

How to make this query with lambda expression in Entity Framework?

```
select 
    s.StudentID, s.StudentName, s.StudentSurName, s.Point 
from 
    Student s
join 
    StudentContest sc on s.StudentID = sc.StudentId
join 
    Contest c on c.ContextID = sc.ContestId 
where 
    c.ContextDate < GETDATE()
```

Comment: Is it important to have just those columns form Studnet (and are there more)?

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell which EF version this is. And show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I made a model based on classes to show results

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            DataBase db = new DataBase();

            var results = (from s in db.Student
                           join sc in db.StudentContest on s.StudentID equals sc.StudentId
                           join c in db.Contest.Where(x => x.ContextDate < date) on sc.ContextID equals c.ContestId
                           select new { StudentID = s.StudentID, StudentName = s.StudentName, StudentSurName = s.StudentSurName, Point = s.Point }
                           ).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class DataBase
    {
        public List<StudentContest> StudentContest { get; set; }
        public List<Student> Student { get; set; }
        public List<Contest> Contest { get; set; }
    }
    public class StudentContest
    {
        public string StudentId { get; set;}
        public string ContextID { get; set;}
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public string StudentID { get; set;}
        public string StudentName { get; set;}
        public string StudentSurName { get; set;}
        public string Point { get; set;}
    }
    public class Contest
    {
        public string ContestId { get; set;}
        public DateTime ContextDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for help I will  use this linq expression .for now but I want to lampda expression  for example: _contestDal.GetAll().Where(x=>) .. .. .. .. .. . . .

Comment: It is much easier to understand where way I did it.

Comment: My objectionhere is that you encourage mindless copying of SQL to LINQ. You should encourage using navigation properties instead.